# Difference between dconf power settings and Upower.conf?

Tags: suspend, dconf

Ubuntu 18.04.

I am fiddling with settings on my Dell 7490 laptop to have it not go to sleep when on low battery.

I have got it to work but only after combining dconf settings in org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power and /etc/UPower/UPower.conf settings.

Could somebody please explain what the difference between the two are, and if one takes priority over the other.

Thank you

Comment: As you have experience in this area, can I solicit a comment on another user's question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149643/laptop-not-shutting-down-on-low-power/1150124#1150124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/etc/UPower/UPower.conf
```

takes precedence. Gnome moved from using `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` for some of the options to this file so UPower.conf is a newer approach.

The [file](https://gist.github.com/RobbiNespu/ee3033954fc15653a800a4a5823c84ee) even claims users should not need to edit the file. So if you need to make changes to `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` to make something work do consider this a bug that needs to be reported as it should affect every user that uses the same hardware.