# Unable to change thresholds for low and critical battery

Tags: power-management, battery

I have tried to change the low and critical battery thresholds but the OS still does not seem to recognize that.

What I have tried:

1. Changing `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` to:

```
    UsePercentageForPolicy=true
    PercentageLow=30
    PercentageCritical=20
    PercentageAction=20
    CriticalPowerAction=HybridSleep
```

The file maintains the modifications but still the laptop notifies me of low battery at the default 10%

2. Changing the same values with `dconf-editor` in `org` -> `gnome` -> `settings-daemon` -> `plugins` -> `power`

Still the laptop notifies me when the battery reaches 10% instead of 30%.

3. using the command line, like:
   `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 30`

The the laptop continues to behave as if there's no change. I have been trying to solve this problem for weeks but I couldn't find a way. I searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find anything that could solve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

Thank you sancho.s for your great suggestions. I did set the `use-time-for-policy` value to false already. I double checked and it seems that is indeed false.

Your temporary workaround unfortunately doesn't seem to work. I calculated the ratio you mentioned and I had it at 5%. I changed it to 30% by modifying `alarm` to a number 6x higher. Nothing seems to happen when the battery reaches 30%.

The related links were indeed useful but I already read those answers previously, and tried the suggestions in them, which I also reported in my original question. Unfortunately I couldn't solve the problem.

The version of my Ubuntu is 20.04 LTS, and it's running on a Thinkpad X1. I should point out that I formatted my laptop a few weeks ago, and before formatting, UPower was working correctly on 20.10. Afterwards I changed in the BIOS settings the AHCI to RST but I reverted all the changes before formatting and installing 20.04 LTS. I thought this might be related, but I reverted all the changes and I wouldn't know what to check to make sure there isn't a problem there.

Comment: The Gnome settings are generally ignored when it comes to the notification. Generally how long can your battery last when it hits 30%? 20 minutes?

Comment: At 30% my battery might last 2 or 3 hours, depending on usage. I did also try to change the UPower settings manually but to no avail.

Comment: I want to commend your very unusual detailed question and edits. It really helps others help you.
Your last paragraph suggests some (cumbersome) things you could try.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please be more detailed on which cumbersome things I could try? I really wouldn't know what to try regarding AHCI and I am not even sure it might be related to my problem.

Comment: Check independently if Ubuntu 20.10 with the various BIOS configurations works. Then try with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I checked both 20.10 and 20.04 (live) with the various BIOS configurations, and UPower seems to work fine in all of them. I am inclined to think now that the problem might be related to something in my current system, maybe some program or some configuration that I have changed or that in some way is interfering with UPower.

Answer (score 1):

I did not identify anything wrong with what you did.
Even so, try `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy false`, and rebooting.
Or `sudo systemctl restart upower.service` should preform the same as rebooting.

As a workaround, there are two relevant files in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0` (this location may change depending on the computer, you can easily find it with `locate BAT0` assuming your is `BAT0`).
Check the values in `energy_full` (the same as in variable `POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL` of file `uevent`) and in `alarm`.
The ratio gives you the percentage for an alarm, in my case alarm/energy_full=5%.
You can set it to 10% by calculating target=10%*energy_full, and using that number in `echo <target> | sudo tee /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/alarm`.
YMMV.

In the meantime, please post the brand/model of your computer and Ubuntu version.

**Related**:

1. [How to change critically low battery value?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92794/how-to-change-critically-low-battery-value)
2. [Laptop not shutting down on low power](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149643/laptop-not-shutting-down-on-low-power/)
3. [Difference between dconf power settings and Upower.conf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139336/difference-between-dconf-power-settings-and-upower-conf)

**Related to `.../BAT0/...`**:

2. https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9l5nkv/need_solution_to_handle_low_battery_protocol_with/
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84437/how-do-i-make-my-laptop-sleep-when-it-reaches-some-low-battery-threshold
4. https://linrunner.de/tlp/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful suggestions. I replied in full in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

All the percentage values need to be descending (PercentageLow>PercentageCritical>PercentageAction), otherwise the defaults will be loaded for all values. This condition is not met in your configuration, where PercentageCritical=PercentageAction. I checked the source code of upower and the condition is really defined this way in src/up-daemon.c.